# Is all reputation equal, or was this a bug?

Tags: support, reputation, protected-questions, association-bonus

Due to long use and positive reputation across other stack exchange sites, I've started getting 100 reputation immediately on joining a new stack-exchange site.

A question interested me in a site I had just joined. It showed that I had 100 reputation. However, on trying to answer the question I found that I was blocked with a message that because this question was highly active, I needed to earn 10 reputation before answering.

Reloading the page did not resolve this. Was this by design because my reputation did not come from that particular site? Or was that a bug?

Comment: The association bonus doesn't count as earned reputation. The language in the notice could certainly make it clearer what "earned" means, though.

Comment: Between the two linked questions, you should have your answer! :) Essentially, the Association bonus (that 100 points you get) doesn't get you past the protections on those highly active questions. :)

Comment: The notice used to be clearer, but it regressed for unknown reasons...

Comment: @Luuklag well, there is a [new request to improve it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349543/protected-question-notice-is-confusing-and-incorrect-especially-to-users-with-t) now. :)